# JQuery get the current checkboxes value next to the selected button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using JQuery 3 and [iCheck library](http://icheck.fronteed.com/) for my checkboxes. I create my HTML from the Ajax response. I have x json objects then I create x card and in each card I create multiple checkboxes from the services array property in my json. Each card has a button to select the current card.

So if I got 2 objects it looks like this :

[image]

The HTML of 1 card in the Ajax success looks like this :

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="box box-primary">
      <div class="box-header with-border">
        <div class="box-tools pull-right"></div>
        <h3 class="box-title">Title 1</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="box-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <ul class="services">
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="1"/> Service 1 - 82.00€
                </label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="2"/> Service 2 - 45.00€
                </label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="3"/> Service 3 - 15.00€
                </label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="4"/> Service 4 - 10.00€
                </label>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block select-box">Select this box</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the Ajax success, inside the json loop I create the event for each button:

```
    $('.select-box').on('click', function () {
      console.log('test');
    });
```

But I have a problem because I don't know how can I get only the current checkboxes value according to the selected card. For example if you look my image, if I click on the first card I want the value of service 1 and 2 but if I click on the second card I don't want to get them because there is no checked service.

How can I get the current selected checkboxes value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(this)` to specify the button the user actually clicked. Details commenterd in demo.

```js
// When any button.select-box is clicked...
$('.select-box').on('click', function(e) {

  /*
  Find the ul.services that is positioned before the clicked button.select-box
  */
  var services = $(this).prev('.services');
  
  /*
  Then find each checked checkbox and log their values
  */
  services.find(':checked').each(function(i) {
    console.log($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="box box-primary">
      <div class="box-header with-border">
        <div class="box-tools pull-right"></div>
        <h3 class="box-title">Title 1</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="box-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <ul class="services">
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="1"/> Service 1 - 82.00€
                </label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="2"/> Service 2 - 45.00€
                </label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="3"/> Service 3 - 15.00€
                </label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="4"/> Service 4 - 10.00€
                </label>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block select-box">Select this box</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="box box-primary">
      <div class="box-header with-border">
        <div class="box-tools pull-right"></div>
        <h3 class="box-title">Title 2</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="box-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <ul class="services">
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="5"/> Service 5 - 82.00€
                </label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="6"/> Service 6 - 45.00€
                </label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="7"/> Service 7 - 15.00€
                </label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="8"/> Service 8 - 10.00€
                </label>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block select-box">Select this box</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, does it works if you have the same checkbox value in your 2 different cards ?

Comment: Yes, it only gets the checked checkboxes that are positioned directly before the button the user has clicked.

Comment: Cool ! I tested in my code and it works thank you so much. I just set an id in my loop when I attach the event to my button : `$('#select-box-'+data.id).on('click', function () ` and I put your code inside and it's exactly what I need !

Comment: That's great but keep in mind that `#id` is rarely needed when using jQuery, `.class` is sufficient 99% of the time. As you become more proficient, it'll become more apparent. Happy coding!

Comment: I can't use class here because I create my html dynamically and I attach the event inside the loop so when I click on a button all click event on this class will be triggered

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you are not 'creating the event for each button' you are attaching an event handler for all buttons multiple times. 
You can set unique id's to each cart and then attach event handlers based on id

```
$('#card-1 .select-box').on('click', function () {
    console.log('test');
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you I added an id for each button then I attached the event to this id. But my problem with the checkboxes still append. I don't know how to scope my checkboxes to get the closest services

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. Check the snippest below.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  
  $(document).on('click', ".select-box", function() {// Attaching the event on all buttons (even the new), you don't need to put the eventlistener in the loop

    var checkboxes = $(this).siblings("ul.services").find("input");
  // $(this) refer to the button, use siblings to catch your ul and use find to get all your inputs
    checkboxes.each(function() {
    
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) { //$(this) refers to the current element in the loop
        console.log($(this).val());
        // Do some stuff if it's checked
      }

    })
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="box box-primary">
      <div class="box-header with-border">
        <div class="box-tools pull-right"></div>
        <h3 class="box-title">Title 1</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="box-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <ul class="services">
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="1"/> Service 1 - 82.00€
                </label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="2"/> Service 2 - 45.00€
                </label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="3"/> Service 3 - 15.00€
                </label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="4"/> Service 4 - 10.00€
                </label>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block select-box">Select this box</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

A little more :

```
 $(document).on('click',selector, function() { //stuff}
```

With this syntax you will attach a click event on all elements according to your selector (older or newer). It's nice to know this.

If you want to refer to a specific block of elements try to scope it according to your trigger element. You can use `closest(),find(),siblings() ...`